# React local element not updating?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-component

I have a component which has a local variable

```
  let endOfDocument = false;
```

And I have a infinite scroll function in my useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
const { current } = selectScroll;
current.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (current.scrollTop + current.clientHeight >= current.scrollHeight) {
    getMoreExercises();
  }
});
return () => {
  //cleanup
  current.removeEventListener('scroll', () => {});
};
}, []);
```

In my getMoreExercises function I check if we reached the last document in firebase

```
function getMoreExercises() {
 if (!endOfDocument) {
  let ref = null;
  if (selectRef.current.value !== 'All') {
    ref = db
      .collection('exercises')
      .where('targetMuscle', '==', selectRef.current.value);
  } else {
    ref = db.collection('exercises');
  }
  ref
    .orderBy('average', 'desc')
    .startAfter(start)
    .limit(5)
    .get()
    .then((snapshots) => {
      start = snapshots.docs[snapshots.docs.length - 1];

      if (!start) endOfDocument = true; //Here

      snapshots.forEach((exercise) => {
        setExerciseList((prevArray) => [...prevArray, exercise.data()]);
      });
    });
}
}
```

And when I change the options to another category I handle it with a onChange method

```
  function handleCategory() {
    endOfDocument = false;
    getExercises();
  }
```

I do this so when we change categories the list will be reset and it will no longer be the end of the document. However the endOfDocument variable does not update and getMoreExercise function will always have the endOfDocument value of true once it is set to true. I cannot change it later. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Local variables do not persist between renders. You need to make it stateful using `useState`.

Comment: I have tried it and even though the state will change to true, when checking for the endOfDocument "if (!endOfDocument)",  it will for some reason still be false when my getMoreExercise function is called.  If that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DevLoverUmar mentioned, that would updated properly,
but since the endOfDocument is basically never used to "render" anything, but just a state that is used in an effect, I would put it into a `useRef` instead to reduce unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: May I ask how you would do that?

Comment: Thank you, I accomplished my goal by using useRef.

let endOfDocument = useRef(false);

and changing values with endOfDocument.current = true or false depending on situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `setExerciseList` as a react useState hook variable. You should use useState for endOfDocument as well as suggested by Brian Thompson in a comment.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
const [endOfDocument,setEndOfDocument] = useState(false);

function handleCategory() {
    setEndOfDocument(false);
    getExercises();
  }
```